# k-fold cross validation on train set after splitting into train/test

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a question in using in an imbalance dataset both 80/20 split and k-fold cross validation, i.e.:

```
- Split data into train and test set (80/20)
- Use 10-fold cross validation on the train data set.
- Choose hyperparameters which perform best on the k validation sets.
- Train this best model on complete training data
- Get an unbiased performance estimate on test set
- Train best model on complete data set
- Predict future data using final model
```

What would be the pros? What about the cons?

Comment: I am not sure precisely what you intend to mean by "unbiased" in *"Get an unbiased performance estimate on test set"*, and both $80/20$ and $10$-fold are slightly arbitrary, the the justification is that empirically the approach you describe seems to perform better on out-of-sample predictions than some other approaches

Comment: Not sure what the question is? However, iff the splitting is done correctly (i.e. independence between the sets is achieved), the performance on the test set is an unbiased performance estimate for the model trained on the 80 % training data. Wrt the final model trained on the complete data set, we'd expect a (slight) pessimistic bias.